# Create dataframe in R based on position from a grouped list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, group-by

I have been trying to extract values from a dataframe based on the positions stored in a list, grouped by id. Specifically in the following reproducible example, I have a list (l1) with certain row positions of the datafrmame (df), grouped by id.

```
id1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
ind1 <- c(1,3,5,8,9,10,12,14,17,1,3)
l1<-list(id1,ind1)

id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
v2 <- c(5,6,1,2,4,5,8,9,12,12,2,3,6,7,8,1,9,4,19,2,5,6,3,4,9)

df<- data.frame(id,v2)
```

I would like to create a new dataframe with the values of the variable v2 in the positions specified in l1. Desired output:

```
v3 <- c(5,1,4,9,12,12,3,7,9,5,3)
id2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)

output <- data.frame(v3,id2)
```

I am kind of lost on how to approach this, I tried:

```
output <- group_by(id) %>% df[nrow(v2)==nrow(l1),]
```

But I get the error message:

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :    no applicable method for
> 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which` in `mapply` to get the desired index in *df*.

```
data.frame(v3 = df$v2[mapply(function(i, j) which(i == df$id)[j],
 l1[[1]], l1[[2]])], id2 = l1[[1]])
#   v3 id2
#1   5   1
#2   1   1
#3   4   1
#4   9   1
#5  12   1
#6  12   1
#7   3   1
#8   7   1
#9   9   1
#10  5   2
#11  3   2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it worked. I was wondering, in case I have a really long nested list is there a way to modify this without including every index manually? ( l1[[1]], l1[[2]] ... etc)

Comment: Maybe you give an example data showing this case and maybe in a new question.